# Why does cabal install reinstall packages already in .cabal/lib

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm attempting to use CircleCI to build some Haskell projects. Circle automatically caches the `/home/ubuntu/.cabal` directory after each build and I thought that would speed up the builds, but they seem to take just as long as before---all that's skipped is the download step.

The build instructions I'm using are

```
cabal update
cabal install --only-dependencies --enable-tests
cabal configure --enable-tests
cabal build
cabal test
```

and I anticipated that `install --only-dependencies` step would see the cache and run more quickly.

What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an [excellent Reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/12alw1/why_inbreeding_is_bad_for_your_community_cabal/) of cabal issues a few months back. My recollection is that Haskell has no specified application binary interface, and that the `ghc` compiler does a lot of aggressive inter-library graph reductions during compilation. As a result, there is no such thing as a stable library installation in a Haskell app -- any library is liable to be dragged down and recompiled against the full set of already-installed libraries.

The bottom line here is that caching the `.cabal/lib` directory does nothing to speed installation. Recompilation of dependencies will always happen. Your best approach, aside from sandboxing using `hsenv`, is to specify your full set of dependent libraries when you call `cabal install`. That way, the dependencies can be calculated ahead of time, and compilation should only occur once.

Haskell gurus, please feel free to correct me if anything I said here is mistaken. I have been out of the Haskell loop for a few months, and I'm aware that cabal/library issues have received a lot of attention lately.